# Would a PNG geyser work on biogas?

Tags: energy, heat, hydrocarbons, fuel, petrochemistry

I am trying to understand if a water heater designed to run on piped natural gas (PNG) could be powered by biogas without any modifications. Typically, these [geysers](https://www.racold.com/gas-water-heaters) have a battery-powered ignition and appropriate nozzles to generate flames. From a chemistry viewpoint, my two questions are:

1. Would biogas ignite with the same ignition setup as PNG's? I am not sure about the right terms but thinking of the time required for a spark to start the flames on PNG versus biogas.
2. Would the same nozzles hold well or do the hole diameters need to be adjusted to achieve greater (or lower) gas flow to generate the same degree of heat?

Comment: Both PNG and biogas are mostly methane, but the latter contains significantamount of CO2 ( typically 25-50% ), so it would need less air for optimal combustion.

Comment: One problem would be the [acid gases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_gas).  Allegedly, it is possible to construct a DIY device that removes acid gases from biogas using, say, kitchen-grade sodium bicarbonate.

Comment: You might find producer gas (https://www.vedantu.com/chemistry/producer-gas) is similar enough to biogas that a simple gas orifice interchange to producer gas would suffice -- or *not*. Perhaps a local HVAC company could help on specifics.